# HighChart Data label issue in bar chart

Tags: javascript, jquery, bar-chart, highcharts

I want the label outside the bar stack. I've used below code but it doesn't work everytime.

[image]

```
 dataLabels: {
              enabled: true,
              color: '#333',
              inside:false
          },
```

[**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/EhMRV/1/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go:

```
dataLabels: {
          enabled: true,
          color: '#333',
          inside: false,
          crop: false,
          overflow: "none"
      },
```

http://jsfiddle.net/kq2xgwhg/

Documented here: http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#plotOptions.series.dataLabels under "overflow".

Answer (score 1):

There are different ways to position your data labels, you can set their x & y positions and you can also set position for each data point individually but as you have both negative and positive values and even if you don't it will be quite a headache. `inside: false` doesn't seem to be doing anything but i managed to find another easier solution for you which is the use of `rotation` property of the data label.. setting to even '1' takes the labels outside.

```
dataLabels: {
     rotation: 1,
     enabled: true,
     color: '#333',
},
```

**[See the DEMO here](http://jsfiddle.net/EhMRV/2/)**

Now you can play around with different angles and width heights to see what suits you best.